# XML/JSON comparison: XML writes faster, JSON reads faster - is my measurement wrong?

Tags: java, xml, json, performance, jaxb

*DISCLAIMER: I do not want to discuss about JSON and XML. Really.*

I made the following benchmark and I wonder if I am totally wrong:

## #1

I made a simple model of Java POJOs (a course which has a list of students as well as a list of topics and some properties just as a name). It looks like this:

```
public class Course {

  private String          name;
  private String          description;
  private int             rating;
  private List< Student > students = new ArrayList<>();
  private List< Topic >   topics   = new ArrayList<>();

  // getter and setter...
}

public class Student {
    ...
}

public class Topic {
    ...
}
```

## #2

I generated a course instance with let's say 10.000 Students and 10.000 topics and initialized it with random values:

```
Course course = new Course();

for ( int i = 0 + t; i < 10000 + t; i++ ) {
  Student student = new Student();
  student.setAge( ( int ) ( 100 * Math.random() ) + t );
  student.setName( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
  course.getStudents().add( student );
}

for ( int i = 0 + t; i < 10000 + t; i++ ) {
  Topic topic = new Topic();
  topic.setDescription( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
  topic.setDifficulty( ( int ) ( 10 * Math.random() ) + t );
  topic.setName( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
  topic.setRating( ( int ) ( 10 * Math.random() ) + t );
  course.getTopics().add( topic );
}
```

## #3

I wrote this `Course` object to a file (500 times in a loop) and measured the time with XML and JSON. And I read the object from a file (500 times in a loop), also with XML and JSON. For example, here is the code I used to write the the object as JSON and the code I used to write it as XML:

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter( this.jsonFile );
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Course course = createCourse( i );
gson.toJson( course, writer );
writer.close();

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Course.class );
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false );
Course course = createCourse( i );
jaxbMarshaller.marshal( course, this.xmlFile );
```

## #4

I did this with 200, 2.000, 20.000, 100.000 and 200.000 students and topics in the course object. The result was the following:

- The XML file is read much slower than the JSON file.
- The JSON file is written slower than the XML file, but not that much. Also, if I use a small object (200 and 2.000 students/topics), JSON is a little bit faster (but nearly the same).

The Google Doc with more details is at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t6tRfja6cKEnl7oYxSa69bwDvIcDniy9lK5rzOZqb30/edit?usp=sharing

## #5

I used:

- Java 8
- GSON for JSON
- JAXB for XML

## Question

Is there any logical explanation for my results? Did I make an obvious mistake in my measurements? Or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Your conclusion: Gson starts faster but becomes slower when writing bigger collections?

Comment: My conclusion: JAXB writes faster, GSON reads faster. For small files, GSON also writes faster, but not much. But I think for small files, the IO operation is much more work than the actually parsing...

Comment: Can you try the same thing with Jackson for JSON? I feel like Gson isn't caching its serializers as much as it could.

Comment: Of course I can :) - So I made the same test with Jackson and the result is a little bit different. Such as GSON, Jackson reads much faster than JAXB for XML. However, Jackson also writes faster than JAXB (while GSON writes slower). I updated the Goolge Doc. But could there be any other explanation for the fast reading expect of the actual implementation? I mean, reading JSON is more then twice as fast as reading XML.

Comment: JSON is more compact than XML. Other than that, it's implementation details. (It might also have to do with how XML needs to match full element names (some times) for its closing tags, while JSON only has to match `}` or `]`.)